# Confusion with inner product linearity in complex

Tags: inner-products, sesquilinear-forms

For a sesquilinear form, I have encountered two sources that say completely opposite things.

During my lecture, my teacher said $\langle \alpha v|w\rangle=\alpha^*\langle v|w\rangle$ but in Wikipedia and other school's lecture notes they say $\langle v|\alpha w\rangle=\alpha^*\langle v|w\rangle$. $\alpha^*$ denotes the complex conjugate of the constant $\alpha$. So I was wondering which one is more natural? Or is it ok as long as I keep it consistent?

Comment: Yes, so long as you are consistent, it's fine, though some formulas will look slightly different depending on your precise definition. This is, at heart, a clash of conventions between mathematicians and physicists; the latter like their inner products to be linear in the second component, and mathematicians like them to be linear in the first component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a difference between the physicist notation, which is linear in the second term, and the mathematical notation, which is linear in the first term. The physicist notation is better on account of lending power to Dirac notation. However, there is no real conflict, as long as you know your author's convention.